# update ui when array element is updated

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to update UI when array propety is updated ,

I have array of colors , I trying to update the color red in colors array but it doesnot update the UI

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.self = this;

  self.colors = ko.observableArray([
    { color: "red", test: "aaa" },
    { color: "blue", test: "bbb" },
    { color: "yellow", test: "ccc" }
  ]);

  self.replaceIt = function() {
    const result = self.colors().filter(c => c.color === "red");
    result[0].color = "green";
    for (var i = 0; i < self.colors().length; i++) {
      self.colors.replace(self.colors()[0], result[0]);
    }
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: colors">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text:color"></span>
    <span data-bind="text:test"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<br/>
<br/>

<button data-bind="click:replaceIt">Replace It</button>
```

the result UI always display

```
red aaa
blue bbb
yellow ccc
```

but I want to update UI when I update property red to green

```
green aaa
blue bbb
yellow ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in your setup the `color` property is not observable itself,
you have to update the `observableArray` with a fully new array item in order to get the change tracking triggered.

```
self.colors.replace(result, { color: "green", test: result.test });
```

See working demo below.

```js
 var ViewModel = function() {

    this.self = this;

    self.colors = ko.observableArray([
        {color: 'red' , test:"aaa"},
        {color: 'blue' , test:"bbb"},
        {color: 'yellow' , test:"ccc"}    
        ]);

    self.replaceIt = function() {

        const result = self.colors().filter(c => c.color ==="red")[0];
        if (result)    
        {   
            self.colors.replace(result, { color: "green", test: result.test });
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: colors">
    <li>
    <span data-bind="text:color"></span>   
    <span data-bind="text:test"></span>

    </li>
</ul>
<br/>
<br/>

<button data-bind="click:replaceIt">Replace It</button>
```

Comment: thank you @pfx for reply , but I was wondering if i have a big object like 30 property not only two as mentioned in the question and I want to update only one property , should I map all other 29 properties  like you do in the answer, or should be a way to map them dynamically without writing them one by one

Comment: @ali I would make a viewmodel for the objects stored in the `colors` array, having an observable `color` property. Doing so, just changing the `color` to green updates the UI and you don't have to manipulate the array via the `replace`.
Both solutions will work, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @ali another possibility is to use [ko.mapping](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to help with mapping/converting large dto's to knockout view models